# isEqualToString not working properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, calendar

I'm making an app that creates a new calendar and then uses that calendar to add events, etc.
I can create the calendar just fine, but I'm trying to run a check to see if the calendar exists, and of so, don't create a second one with the same name every time. In other words, only create the new calendar ONCE.

I'm setting an int variable and running a loop to check the title property of each calendar on the device, but the int variable never gets changed, even though the string for the calendar name I'm searching for matches.

Here's what I have for the "check for calendar" code:

```
-(void)checkForCalendar {

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    NSArray *calendarArray = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
    //NSLog(@"%@", calendarArray);

    for (int x = 0; x < [calendarArray count]; x++) {

        EKCalendar *cal = [calendarArray objectAtIndex:x];
        NSString *title = [cal title];
        if ([title isEqualToString:@"AFTP"] ) {
            calendarExists = 1;
        }else{
            calendarExists = 0;
        }
    }

[self createCalendar];

}
```

And here's what I have for the "create" calendar part: (which works fine, I'm just always getting a "0" instead of a 1 for `calendarExists` int.)

```
-(void)createCalendar {

    NSLog(@"%d",calendarExists);
    if (calendarExists == 0) {
        EKEventStore* eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

        NSString* calendarName = @"AFTP";
        EKCalendar* calendar;

        // Get the calendar source
        EKSource* localSource;
        for (EKSource* source in eventStore.sources) {
            if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV)
            {
                localSource = source;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!localSource)
            return;

        calendar = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:eventStore];
        calendar.source = localSource;
        calendar.title = calendarName;

        [eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this section of your code:

```
    if ([title isEqualToString:@"AFTP"] ) {
        calendarExists = 1;
    }else{
        calendarExists = 0;
    }
```

You need to break after you set your variable to 1, else the next turn of the loop is going to set it back to 0 again:

```
    if ([title isEqualToString:@"AFTP"] ) {
        calendarExists = 1;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks darren, that was definitely the problem. Thank you so much.